# How to prove that for $K$ $\mathbb{Z}$-free & $Q$ projective, $K\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}Q$ is a projective?

Tags: homological-algebra, projective-module, free-modules

Let $K$ be $\mathbb{Z}$-free and $Q$ a projective $\mathbb{Z}G$ module then $K\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}Q$ is a projective $\mathbb{Z}G$-module. I believe that this follows from the adjoint isomorphism theorem:

$Hom_{\mathbb{Z}G}(K\otimes Q, N)=Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(K,Hom_{\mathbb{Z}G}(Q,N))$

But I don't understand why? Any ideas would be helpful, I just don't know where to start.

Comment: Hint : using the equality you wrote as an isomorphism of functors in $N$, show that the functors $Hom_{\mathbb{Z}G}(K\otimes Q,.)$ is exact.

Comment: Well $Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(K,-)$ is exact as it is over an abelian category so $Hom_{\mathbb{Z}G}(K\otimes Q,-)$ must also be exact?

Comment: Remember a module $M$ is projective iff $Hom(M,.)$ is exact. Then $Hom_{\mathbb{Z}G}(K\otimes Q,.)$ can be written as the composite of two exact functors...

Comment: Why do we need to write it it as the composite of two exact functors? Can't we directly conclude that as $Hom_{\mathbb{Z}G}(K\otimes Q, _)$ is exact $K\otimes Q$ is projective from the condition you just wrote?

Comment: I don't understand : you are trying to prove that $K\otimes Q$ is projective right ? In other words, you are trying to prove that $Hom_{\mathbb{Z}G}(K\otimes Q,.)$ is exact.

Comment: Yes, but I thought that as the LHS was exact the RHS must be too as they are isomorphic...

Comment: You don't know that the LHS is exact, this is what you are trying to prove !! The RHS is because this is the composite of two exact functors and thus the LHS is.

Comment: Sorry I meant LHS and RHS the other way around *facepalm* I think I get it now though, thanks.